# Criterion for continuity at a point.

Tags: general-topology

Textbook definition of continuity at a point:

$\forall W\in N(f(x_0)) : f^{-1}[W]\in N(x_0)$

Possibly, a criterion for continuity at a point:

$\forall U\in T_Y : f(x_0)\in U \rightarrow f^{-1}[U] \in T_X$

If criterion holds, then the defintion holds. It is easy to check.

But I don't see how the reverse can be proved.

I proved only that this follows from the definition

$\forall U\in T_Y : f(x_0)\in U \rightarrow f^{-1}[U] \in N(x_0)$

1. Is there a counterexample when the definition and the criterion are not equivalent?
2. What are requiremnts to topology, so they may become equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion is *not* equivalent to continuity.

For instance, consider on $\Bbb R$ the usual topology and consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\in[-1,1]\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is continuous at $0$, but $(-1,1)$ is an open set to which $f(0)$  and, however, $f^{-1}\bigl((-1,1)\bigr)=[-1,1]$, which is not an open set.